# Exception Certificate Error Thumbnail running django local

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I'm running my server django and setting debug true for THUMBNAIL, to see why thumbnail doesn't show img at templates and at call localhost i've received this exception

CertificateError at /
hostname 'myhost.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'
    enter code here

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'suit',
'tinymce',
'daterange_filter',
'django.contrib.admin',
'import_export',
'south',
'djcelery',
'sorl.thumbnail',
'base',
'accounts',
'app',
'faq',
'marketing',
'website')
Installed Middleware:
  ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


 Template error:
 In template Desarrollo/project/templates/includes/class.html, error at line 82
  hostname 'myhost.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'
 72 :             {% else %}


 73 :                 {% if item.old_price %}


 74 :                     <div class="triangle old"></div>


 75 :                     <div class="text-triangle old">


 76 :                         <small>Ahora</small>


 77 :                         <br><span


 78 :                             class="price">{{ item.price|exchangeRateSymbol:request }}{{ item.price|exchangeRateValue:request }}</span>


 79 :                     </div>


 80 :                 {% endif %}


 81 :             {% endif %}


 82 :              {% thumbnail item.preview "600x360" crop="center" as im %} 


 83 :                 <img data-src="{{ im.url }}" src="" alt="{{ item.name }}" class="img-responsive lazy"/>


 84 :             {% endthumbnail %}


 85 :             <div class="mask">


 86 :                 <a href="{% url 'classes-details' item.slug %}"><p><span


 87 :                         class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle see-more"></span></p></a>


 88 :                 <a href="{% url 'classes-details' item.slug %}" class="info">Ver más</a>


 89 :             </div>


 90 :         </div>


 91 :     {% endif %}


 92 :     <div class="detail_">


Traceback:
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
 112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
 87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/Desarrollo/project/website/views.py" in get
 124.             context_instance = RequestContext(request)
 File "Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
 29.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
 169.         return t.render(context_instance)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 140.             return self._render(context)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
 134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
 123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
 134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "/Desarrollo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
 62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
 305.                 return nodelist.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
 196.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
 155.         return self.render_template(self.template, context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render_template
 137.         output = template.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 140.             return self._render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
 134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
 305.                 return nodelist.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/templatetags/thumbnail.py" in render
 59.             return self._render(context)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/templatetags/thumbnail.py" in _render
 137.         thumbnail = get_thumbnail(file_, geometry, **options)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/shortcuts.py" in get_thumbnail
 8.     return default.backend.get_thumbnail(file_, geometry_string, **options)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/base.py" in get_thumbnail
 101.         if not thumbnail.exists():
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/images.py" in exists
 111.         return self.storage.exists(self.name)
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py" in exists
 414.         return k.exists()
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py" in exists
 539.         return bool(self.bucket.lookup(self.name, headers=headers))
 File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py" in lookup
  142.         return self.get_key(key_name, headers=headers)
  File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py" in get_key
  192.         key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
  File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py" in _get_key_internal
  199.                                                 query_args=query_args)
  File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py" in make_request
  664.             retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py" in make_request
  1071.                           retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py" in _mexe
  943.                                        request.body, request.headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in request
  1048.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_request
  1088.         self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in endheaders
  1044.         self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_output
  888.         self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in send
  850.                 self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in connect
  1269.                                                   server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in wrap_socket
  352.                          _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in __init__
  579.                     self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in do_handshake
  816.             match_hostname(self.getpeercert(), self.server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in match_hostname
  271.             % (hostname, ', '.join(map(repr, dnsnames))))

  Exception Type: CertificateError at /
  Exception Value: hostname 'myhost.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

This is my configuration settings.py at media url and static for production:

```
BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\','/')
MEDIA_URL = 'http://myhost.s3.amazonaws.com/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = 'http://myhost.s3.amazonaws.com/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   join(BASE_DIR, 'static').replace('\\','/'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

and media and static variables local_settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CDN = '/static/'
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Python introduced strict certificate checking in version 2.7.9 (see [PEP 476](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/)) that causes buckets with dots in their names to fail on load. This is a bug on the AWS site ([ref](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836)). If you remove the dots from the name it seems to fix the issue, or downgrading python to 2.7.8 (I think).

I found downgrading python within 2.7 too difficult though, so I just commented out the code manually.

> sudo vim /usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py line 271

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py in match_hostname
                if key == 'commonName':
                    if _dnsname_match(value, hostname):
                        return
                    dnsnames.append(value)
    if len(dnsnames) > 1:
        raise CertificateError("hostname %r "
            "doesn't match either of %s"
                        % (hostname, ', '.join(map(repr, dnsnames)))) ...
    elif len(dnsnames) == 1:
        raise CertificateError("hostname %r "
            "doesn't match %r"
            % (hostname, dnsnames[0]))
    else:
        raise CertificateError("no appropriate commonName or "
```